# Fetch data based on time slot in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

How to show number of count data in date-wise by time slots.

we have **slots**

> [{'startTime': "2017-04-20T08:30:00.000Z",
>       'endTime':  "2017-04-20T09:30:00.000Z"},
>
> {'startTime': "2017-04-20T09:30:00.000Z",
>         'endTime':  "2017-04-20T10:30:00.000Z"},
>
> {'startTime': "2017-04-20T10:30:00.000Z",
>        'endTime':  "2017-04-20T18:30:00.000Z"}]

**Input**

```
[{
   "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-04-20T09:20:00.167Z"),
 },
 {
   "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-04-20T14:20:00.167Z") 
 },
 {
   "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-04-20T11:20:00.167Z")
 },
 {
   "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-04-20T14:20:00.167Z")
 },
{
  "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-04-20T12:20:00.167Z")
}]
```

To show data in this format

**output**

> [{'startTime': "2017-04-20T08:30:00.000Z",
>       'endTime':  "2017-04-20T09:30:00.000Z",
>       'count' : 1},
>
> {'startTime': "2017-04-20T09:30:00.000Z",
>         'endTime':  "2017-04-20T10:30:00.000Z",
>          'count':0 },
>
> {'startTime': "2017-04-20T10:30:00.000Z",
>      'endTime':  "2017-04-20T18:30:00.000Z"},
>       'count' : 4]

Answer (score 1):

```
var tempData = [], 

for(var i = 0; i <inputData.length ; i++){
    var condition =  {
      '$sum':{'$cond':  
                [{'$and': 
                     [{'$gte': ['$checkinData.time', new Date(inputData[i].startTime)]},
                      {'$lt' : ['$checkinData.time', new Date(inputData[i].endTIme)]}
                    ]},1,0]
                }
        }

        tempData.push(condition);
    }
```

Comment: Provide some explanation to the answer as to why/how this code would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MongoDB's `$gte`(greater than or equal to), `$lte`(less than or equal to), `$gt`(greater than)
 and `$lt`(less than) to specify a range of dates. You can specify the "from" date in `$gte/$gt` and the "to" date in `$lte/$lt`.

So your query should look like this -

```
db.collection.count({createdAt: {$gte: "your from date in ISO date object format", $lte: "your to date in ISO date object format"}}, function (err, count){
    //whatever you wanna do with count
})
```

or

```
db.collection.find({createdAt: {$gte: "your from date in ISO date object format", $lte: "your to date in ISO date object format"}}).count(function (err, count){
    //whatever you wanna do with count
})
```

for each slot of time you will have to run this in a loop. So just as an example, it would look like -

```
db.collection.find({createdAt: {$gte: timeRangeArr[i].startTime, $lte: timeRangeArr[i].endTime}}).count(function (err, count){
    //whatever you wanna do with count
})
```

Comment: **Is there any other method without using loop** .suppose we have 10- 20 times slots then you have to iterate 10 -20 times loop according to time slots and query will hit 10 -20 times in data base.

Comment: I dont think so. The query can only take 1 $gte/$gtand 1 $lte/$lt which can again have only 1 value. So it will have to run in a loop. If you are worried about running them in synchronous fashion,  then you can run them in parallel, Check the npm module called async - https://caolan.github.io/async/